# Harmonic Unit Disk Problem with Boundary Function - Dirichlet Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ in the disk $r<1$ having the boundary function: $$u=4\cos(2\theta)+\sin^2(3\theta)$$

I am pretty sure this is a Dirichlet problem... but I can't seem to get a sensible answer.

Comment: Hi Sam and welcome to the site. You are welcome to show any attempts you've made as it may help people to help you. Also good to learn MathJax and LaTeX if you haven't already as it increases the chances of getting positive responses.

Comment: I would guess a good start would be to try and rewrite $sin^2(3\theta)$ in terms of first order $sin$ and $cos$ followed by rewriting the differential equation in polar coordinates.

Comment: Also maybe spherical harmonics could help you at least in part. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics

Answer (score 0):

The functions $r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}$ are harmonic for $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$ because these are the polar forms of the functions $z^{n}$ and $\overline{z^n}$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. Rewrite your function in terms of these:
$$
     4\cos(2\theta)+\sin^2(3\theta)=4\cos(2\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\{1-\cos(6\theta)\}.
$$
The following function is harmonic
$$
          u(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2}+4r^2\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{2}r^6\cos(6\theta),
$$
and
$$
           u(1,\theta)=4\cos(2\theta)+\sin^2(3\theta).
$$